# is yield take considered a non blocking call?

Tags: redux-saga

Is this considered non blocking or can the first take be dropped/missed if action1 is dispatched multiple times?

```
function* nonBlockingSaga () {
    while (true) {
        yield take('action1');
        yield take('action2');
        yield take('action3');
    }
}
```

Comment: I found they added a cheat sheet section [in the docs](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/tree/master/docs/api#blocking--non-blocking)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you dispatch `action1`, the saga will be blocked by `take('action2')` and you will miss any `action1` actions until the saga loops around. To work around/solve this you can use an [action channel](https://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/advanced/Channels.html). An action channel allows you to buffer the actions until your saga is ready to take them.

So in you example this would result in:

```
function* nonBlockingSaga () {
  const channel1 = yield actionChannel('action1');
  const channel2 = yield actionChannel('action2');
  const channel3 = yield actionChannel('action3');
  while (true) {
    yield take(channel1);
    yield take(channel2);
    yield take(channel3);
  }
}
```

This way you will never miss any of the actions.